# in an inner join how to select only one row from the table on right based on a sliding criteria?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I have a set of tables containing weeks, products, inventory and weekly forecasts from which I want to select week X product inventory and latest forecasts. But I just cannot get my hands around the SQL:

```
create table products (
    product_id integer
);
create table inventory (
    product_id integer,
    asof_week integer,
    qoh float8
);
create table forecast (
    product_id integer,
    for_week integer,
    asof_week integer,
    projection float8
);
create table weeks (
    wkno integer
);
insert into weeks values (4),(5),(6),(7);
insert into products values(1),(2);
insert into inventory values(1,5,10),(1,6,20),(2,6,200);
insert into forecast values(1,4,1,10),(1,4,2,11),(1,4,3,12),(1,4,4,13),
                           (1,5,1,11),(1,5,2,11),(1,5,3,21),(1,5,4,31),
--corr:one too many        (1,6,1,10),(1,6,2,11),(1,6,3,12),(1,6,4,22),(1,6,5,32),(1,6,5,42),(1,6,6,42),
                           (1,6,1,10),(1,6,2,11),(1,6,3,12),(1,6,4,22),(1,6,5,42),(1,6,6,42),
                           (1,7,1,10),(1,7,6,16),
                           (2,6,5,2000),(2,7,5,2100),(2,8,5,30);
```

And a query:

```
select p.product_id "product",
        i.asof_week "inven asof",
        i.qoh "qoh",
        f.for_week "fcast for",
        f.projection "fcast qty",
        f.asof_week "fcast asof"
from weeks w, products p
    left join inventory i on(p.product_id = i.product_id)
    left join forecast f on(p.product_id = f.product_id)
where
    (i.asof_week is null or i.asof_week = w.wkno)
    and (f.for_week is null or f.for_week = w.wkno)
    and (f.asof_week is null
        or f.asof_week = (select max(f2.asof_week)
                          from forecast f2
                          where f2.product_id = f.product_id
                             and f2.for_week = f.for_week))
order by p.product_id, i.asof_week, f.for_week, f.asof_week
```

For example, for weeks 4-7, I am looking for a resultset:

```
product week    qoh     projection
1       4       -       13
1       5       10      31
1       6       20      42
1       7       -       16
2       6       200     2000
2       7       -       2100
```

BUT in reality I get only 3 rows:

```
 product | inven asof | qoh | fcast for | fcast qty | fcast asof 
---------+------------+-----+-----------+-----------+------------
       1 |          5 |  10 |         5 |        31 |          4
       1 |          6 |  20 |         6 |        42 |          6
       2 |          6 | 200 |         6 |      2000 |          5
(3 rows)
Time: 2.531 ms
```

I am rather new to SQL and can use some helpful pointers.

Some notes on data: I have several other data tables to join which I have omitted from the example to stay focused on this problem, at least one of them similar in nature to the forecasted quantity table (i.e., with multiple version rows for every product x week). There are about 100 forecast rows for every product X week so somewhere I will also have to worry about efficiency... but correct results first.

I am on postgresql 9.2.

Thanks.

Comment: BTW: the presentation of this question is very complete.(maybe except for the missing PK/FKs) Well done!

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to give general pointers without knowing the rest of your data model, but I should say this: I generally find that queries are easier to reason about when I keep them as "flat" as possible. Also, as soon as I have a bunch of null checks, I either try to add guarantees to my data, or re-pivot my query around a different "root" table.

Anyway, [the following](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/41a0e/13/0) should work for you (although I can't guarantee that it will work for any data, especially in the presence of duplicates):

```
select
  products.product_id,
  weeks.wkno,
  inventory.qoh,
  max(projection)
from forecast
join products on products.product_id = forecast.product_id
join weeks on weeks.wkno = forecast.for_week
left join inventory on
  inventory.product_id = products.product_id
  and inventory.asof_week = weeks.wkno
group by
  products.product_id,
  weeks.wkno,
  inventory.qoh
```

Sorry I can't give you that much advice. I hope this helps.

**Edit**: Tweaked the query to remove the cross join. Original version [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/41a0e/12/0). You might want a cross join if you wanted to left join forecasts if some were missing. For your specific example it's unneeded.

**Edit 2**: The above query is semantically incorrect. The [following](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/e7f4d/4/0) is correct, but is not as illustrative of my point.

```
select
  p.product_id,
  p.wkno,
  p.qoh,
  f.projection
from
  (select
      products.product_id,
      weeks.wkno,
      inventory.qoh,
      max(forecast.asof_week) max_p
    from forecast
    join products on products.product_id = forecast.product_id
    join weeks on weeks.wkno = forecast.for_week
    left join inventory on
      inventory.product_id = products.product_id
      and inventory.asof_week = weeks.wkno
    group by
      products.product_id,
          weeks.wkno,
      inventory.qoh) as p
  join forecast f on
    f.product_id = p.product_id
    and  f.for_week = p.wkno
    and f.asof_week = p.max_p
```

Comment: Julien, thanks, it is closer. I need not max(projection) but {projection : asof_week is most recent}. I see how you have rearranged the joins which is very insightful. +1

Answer (score 1):

There appear to be some PK/FK constraints missing from the data:

```
CREATE TABLE products (
    product_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
    );
CREATE TABLE weeks (
    wkno INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
    );
CREATE TABLE inventory (
    product_id INTEGER REFERENCES products(product_id)
    , asof_week INTEGER REFERENCES weeks(wkno)
    , qoh float8
    , PRIMARY KEY (product_id,asof_week)
    );
CREATE TABLE forecast (
    product_id INTEGER REFERENCES products(product_id)
    , for_week INTEGER REFERENCES weeks(wkno)
    , asof_week INTEGER REFERENCES weeks(wkno)
    , projection FLOAT8
    , PRIMARY KEY (product_id,for_week,asof_week)
    );
INSERT INTO weeks VALUES (4),(5),(6),(7)
    , (1),(2),(3), (8) -- need these, too
    ;
-- et cetera.
```

If the `weeks` table is intended as a "calendar" table, it could (and **should**) be replaced by a `generate_series(4,7)` pseudo-table. (and the FK constraints dropped)

The query suffers al lot from the LEFT JOIN + MAX(aggregate) construct. The following should do the same and looks simpler (`NOT EXISTS` to the rescue ...):

```
SELECT p.product_id "product"
        , i.asof_week "inven asof"
        , i.qoh "qoh"
        , f.for_week "fcast for"
        , f.projection "fcast qty"
        , f.asof_week "fcast asof"
FROM products p
CROSS JOIN weeks w
LEFT JOIN inventory i ON i.product_id = p.product_id AND i.asof_week = w.wkno
LEFT JOIN forecast f ON f.product_id = p.product_id AND f.for_week = w.wkno
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM forecast f2
    WHERE f2.product_id = f.product_id
      AND f2.for_week = f.for_week
    AND  f2.asof_week < f.asof_week
    )
AND COALESCE(i.asof_week,f.for_week) IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY p.product_id, i.asof_week, f.for_week, f.asof_week
    ;
```

Comment: @Julien Langlois: It is a matter of taste. I tend to prefer the 1=1 notation, because it is more explicit (the CROSS Hides things behind a keyword, which looks just like just another noise word) BTW: I did not edit your whitespace, did I?

Comment: Oh okay, fair enough. As for the whitespace, I'm not sure what you mean: if it's that I should have made a comment and not an edit, then I apologize.

Comment: It is not important, but I tend to view other people's work basically as a "work of art", or *at least* as a way of expressing themselves. Even if I don't understand it or if it would conflict with my preferences. (and the whitespace was intended as a joke)

Answer (score 0):

Thank Julien for the tip. This gets the result, although I am not sure if this is the best approach or how it will fare once I have 100+ million rows since I am still working with toy datasets. Probably the first bad thing is `pw` below is unindexed.

```
with pw as ( select * from products, weeks )         
    select pw.product_id "product",
            pw.wkno,         
            i.asof_week "inven asof",    
            coalesce(i.qoh::text,'missing') "qoh",   
            f.for_week "fcast for",       
            coalesce(f.projection::text,'no fcast') "fcast qty",      
            f.asof_week "fcast asof"     
    from pw      
        left join inventory i on(pw.product_id = i.product_id and pw.wkno = i.asof_week )
        left join forecast f on(pw.product_id = f.product_id  
                                and f.for_week = pw.wkno          
                                and f.asof_week = (select max(f2.asof_week)               
                                                from forecast f2                          
                                                where f2.product_id = pw.product_id                       
                                                    and f2.asof_week < pw.wkno                            
                                                    and f2.for_week = pw.wkno))                               
    where        
        not (i.asof_week is null and f.asof_week is null)     
    order by pw.product_id,  
                pw.wkno,     
                f.for_week,                          
                f.asof_week
```

which yields

```
 product | wkno | inven asof |   qoh   | fcast for | fcast qty | fcast asof
---------+------+------------+---------+-----------+-----------+------------
       1 |    4 |            | missing |         4 | 12        |          3
       1 |    5 |          5 | 10      |         5 | 31        |          4
       1 |    6 |          6 | 20      |         6 | 42        |          5
       1 |    7 |            | missing |         7 | 16        |          6
       2 |    6 |          6 | 200     |         6 | 2000      |          5
       2 |    7 |            | missing |         7 | 2100      |          5
(6 rows)
Time: 2.999 ms
```